# Django. Вывод даты окончания абонемента

Tags: django

Нужно вывести информацию о плане и дате окончания абонемента конкретного пользователя. Есть модель Member в ней надо сравнить поле emailID с email пользователя зарегистрированного в базе данных. Данный код не выводит ничего, помогите найти ошибку. Спасибо

## models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    emailid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    joindate = models.DateField(max_length=40)
    expiredate = models.DateField(max_length=40)
    initialamount = models.CharField(max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
def View_Profile(request):
    if Member.emailid == request.user.email:
        prof = Member.objects.all()
    d = {'profile': prof}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', d)
```

## template.html

```
<table id="example" class="table table-hover display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Телефон</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Возраст</th>
                <th>Название плана</th>
                <th>Дата окончания абонимента</th>
                <th>Стоимость плана</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in prof %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.contact}}</td>
                <td>{{i.emailid}}</td>
                <td>{{i.age}}</td>
                <td>{{i.plan}}</td>
                <td>{{i.expiredate}}</td>
                <td>{{i.initialamount}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Member.emailid` сам по себе не вернет сущность member, Вам нужно найти его используя известные данные(email):

```
member = Member.objects.get(emailid=request.user.email)
```

Тут member как раз будет та сущность что Вы ищете, при условии что Вы ее добавили в БД, в этом тоже стоит убедиться, в примере нет намека на то что Вы заполняете эту модель данными.

2. В таких случаях нужно использовать связи между моделями. В вашем случае, полагаю, подойдет `OneToOneField`(Один-к-одному). Суть заключается в том, что Вы можете однозначно связать две модели.

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
    # покажу только реализацию связи
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

У OneToOneField есть и другие параметры, советую ознакомиться в документации. В данном примере первым аргументом передается связываемая первичная модель - `User`/ Вторым - поведение при удаление `models.CASCADE` - означает, что если запись в User удалиться, то и связываемая запись в Member так же будет удалена. Есть разные поведение, так же описанные в доках.

3. Если совсем брать Ваш пример, то на мой взгляд, лучше было бы не делать дополнительную модель, а расширить стандартную модель `User` унаследовавшись от нее.